# How can I force my external monitor to use 4K resolution?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, resolution

I have two identical external monitors (Dell S2722QC) connected to my 14" M1 Pro MacBook Pro. Usually I connect both of them via USB C to a CalDigit Thunderbolt 4 dock with no issues.

Sometimes, however, the second monitor gets incorrectly identified as a 1440p monitor, even though it is a 4K monitor. How do I force it to use a 4K resolution?

In System Preferences, if I "option click" on scaled resolutions for the monitor, I only see resolutions going up to 2560x1440.

[image]

The other monitor can go up to 3840x2160, as expected:

[image]

I tried downloading and using SwitchResX, but it does not show *any* HiDPI resolutions, as shown in the screenshot below. No resolution greater than 2560x1440 is allowed, either.

[image]

A higher resolution/HiDPI resolution is only allowed on the main monitor:

[image]

How do I force set a resolution of 3840x2160?

Comment: what if you don't use the dock, and plug them both in directly? That might point to where the issue lies. Also if that doesn't work what about a different/new cable?

Comment: That might be a possibility—I figured it was a software issue because it's worked fine before, and only intermittently stops working, so there should be a way to "force" the correct resolution. Although it might be an issue with the dock's firmware, which I am not sure about.